# Have a row of fixed width images, but to next line wrap fails if last image is shorter than others

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several fixed width, unspecified height images to display in a row so that they auto scale and keep perspective.

But when I get to the end of the row, if the last image is shorter than any of the other images in the row I cant get it to break to a new line below the longest image.

The succeeding text or block is bunched up beneath the right most image.

I have to do this a lot and would like to use the self justifying width specified height unspecified image window to do so.

I understand this is possible with CSS and Javascript, but wonder if I am missing something and there is an easy way to do this in straight HTML.

As it is I am padding by hand with breaks after the last image in a row so that it will wrap to the next full web page width line properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
clear:left
```

on whatever element you want to put in the next line. That's assuming you have floating elements.